# запуск JS кода на странице из Python

Tags: javascript, python

Моя задача получить список имен в scope браузера на какой-то странице, используя Python. Как параметр функции я получаю URL запроса.

Также есть JS код, который просматривает объекты в scope, фильтрует их по определенным правилам и возвращает массив с именами функций, которые на данный момент объявлены.

В целом, нужно сделать примерно следующее:

1. Открыть страницу по заданному URL.
2. Выполнить JS-код.
3. Получить результат, который возвращает функция JS скрипта.

Все это нужно сделать из Python. Я искал инструменты, с помощью которых можно сделать что-то подобное. Наткнулся на [robobrowser](https://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Почти то, что мне нужно, но я не нашел в документации возможности выполнения JS.

Может быть кто-то может подсказать библиотеки или модули, которые позволяют выполнить JavaScript в браузере после загрузки страницы и получить результат выполнения этого скрипта? Или может быть проимитировать работу браузера из Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

selenium. И работу браузера имитирует, и js-скрипты можно выполнять...

Comment: а есть возможность получить не сам контент страницы, а объекты document или window со страницы в виде какого-то DOM-объекта? И осуществлять манипуляции на JS над объектом DOM, а не над текстом HTML?

Comment: Можно. Расписывать долго, поэтому гуглите что-то вроде "selenium работа с DOM-элементами"

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему, используя selenium. Более подробное описание решения есть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010059/execute-js-code-on-page-from-python)